# Django1.6 IntegrityError despite transaction.atomic()?

Tags: python, concurrency, atomic, gunicorn, django-1.6

Within `transaction.atomic()` I am deleting and re-creating objects.
Django sits behind a 3-worker gunicorn, database is postgres.

**Issue:** When hitting the server with a lot of requests simultaneously, Django is throwing **a few** *IntegrityErrors*:

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "atomic_atomictest_name_key"
DETAIL:  Key (name)=(foo) already exists.
```

Example:

**models.py**

```
class AtomicTest(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(null=False, unique=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def test_atomic(request):
    with transaction.atomic():
        models.AtomicTest.objects.filter(name='foo').delete()
        models.AtomicTest(name='foo').save()
    return http.HttpResponse('OK')
```

The *IntegrityErrors* shouldn't occur in my understanding. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntegrityError` can still happen with `transaction.atomic()`.  The transactions can happen at the same time; they are only isolated from one another until they are committed, at which point it's up to Postgres to try and reconcile the changes.  If Postgres decides one or more transactions is trying to create a row that violates your uniqueness constraint, it will roll back those transactions.

What `transaction.atomic()` does is make sure that ALL COMMANDS in the block are rolled back if any of them fail.  That way you won't have a case where `delete()` succeeds and is committed but `save()` fails.

In this case, `transaction.atomic()` may actually be causing your problem, because it delays `delete()` from taking effect immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. I guess there is no other way than using locks to prevent the db from throwing the IntegrityError?

Comment: In cases where the `IntegrityError` is being caused by a row edit, you can lock the row.  However, in this case it is being caused by a row creation.  There is no way to lock the row except perhaps to manage the locking mechanism manually.  However, in this case the IntegrityError don't seem to be a problem?  After all, the issue is that the row already exists, and there's no need to create it twice.  Maybe you can just catch the error and move on.

Comment: I am doing that now :-) Thanks again!